# How to access template of package to other Meteor application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-packages

[image][Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcWpA.png)
I am developing Meteor application where one package resides in application 1, i want to access templates inside that package to other application called application 2 without adding package to application 2.

Comment: Can you give some code in your question?

Comment: You can't. That's the whole idea of a package, everything is self-contained. Not accessible unless it's been exported.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access a package if it's been added to an application. That's the point of packages. If you'd like to use a package in two different applications, you need to add it to each application.